# Check locally if Linux "gitlab-ci-multirunner" is currently running a job

Tags: linux, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

When I start a maintenance-script via crontab, I'd like to be sure that there is no job running at that moment.

Since I'm already on the shell of the runner-host itself, I'd like to detect locally if there's currently a job running instead of using remote API-calls against the CI-master.

I did not find any command the "gitlab-ci-multirunner" CLI supports that could be used for that. Also I did not find any common indications regarding running processes.

Is there anything I could query to get a save indication of running CI-jobs on that host?